# undefined local variable or method `your_questions_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I receive an error saying that it has an

```
undefined local variable or method 'your_questions_path'
```

My `routes.rb` file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get "/" => "main_app#index"
  get "/location" => "location#location"
  post "/location/index" => "location#index"
  get "/location/index" => "location#index"
  get "/location/directions" => "location#directions"

  root to: 'questions#index'

  resources :questions do
    collection do
      get :your_questions
    end
  end

  get '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
  resources :users, only: [:new, :create]
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create]
  resources :questions, except: [:new] do
    resources :answers, only: [:create]
  end

  get '/register', to: 'users#new'
  get '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
  get '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
  # get '/questions/your_questions', to: 'questions#your_questions' original
  get '/questions/:id', to: 'questions#show'
  get 'search', to: 'controller#action', as: :search
```

My view file with the questions path a.k.a `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <%= link_to 'Home', root_path %>
    </li>

  <% if logged_in? %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to "Your Q's", your_questions_path %>
    </li>
    <li>
      <%= link_to "Logout (#{current_user.username})", logout_path, method: 'get' %>
    </li>
  <% else %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to 'Register', register_path %>
    </li>
    <li>
      <%= link_to 'Login', login_path %>
    </li>
```

I want the questions path to go to `http://localhost:3000/questions/1`

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

The routes you've defined create the following routes:

```
          your_questions_questions GET    /questions/your_questions(.:format)           questions#your_questions
                         questions GET    /questions(.:format)                          questions#index
                                   POST   /questions(.:format)                          questions#create
                      new_question GET    /questions/new(.:format)                      questions#new
                     edit_question GET    /questions/:id/edit(.:format)                 questions#edit
                          question GET    /questions/:id(.:format)                      questions#show
                                   PATCH  /questions/:id(.:format)                      questions#update
                                   PUT    /questions/:id(.:format)                      questions#update
                                   DELETE /questions/:id(.:format)                      questions#destroy
```

The top route is the `your_questions` route, which means you want use:

```
your_questions_questions_path
```

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because you have nested your path inside of a resources block, ie. you have this:

```
resources :questions do
  collection do
    get :your_questions
  end
end
```

if you were to get to this path, (run `rake routes`) you would need to use questions_your_questions_path, however since you want to route to something like `http://localhost:3000/quesitons/1` this is a simple 'show' path that is provided to you by the resources command, instead change your routes file to simply say:

`resources :questions`

and then use `question_path(@question)` where @question is an instance variable set in the controller.

However... also looking from your code, you seem to be wanting the `questions_path` instead since that would provide the `index` action (a listing of questions). You can then in your controller scope the collection of questions to the ones the current user sees...

ie.

```
QuestionsController < ApplicationController

def index
  @questions = current_user.questions
end
```

(assuming your `User` has_many :questions)